# php mysqli fetch_array() gives path with additional backslashes

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a table in a MySql db and I select everything in a single row through php mysqli prepared statements with `fetch_array()`. One of the fields is a path (unix system style with forward slashes `'/'`), but what is coming out is a path with a backslash before each forward slash, like that: `'\/'`.
Specifically, the code I use is the following:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE ID = ?";
    ...
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $res = $stmt->get_result();

    while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($info, $row);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    echo json_encode($info);
```

The result is something like:

```
[{"ID":"a_1338","dir":"\/home\/desktop\/fol\/folid",...}]
```

While originally the path is like this:

```
'/home/desktop/fol/folid'
```

The thing is that I get the right result with `select dir from...` and by using `fetch()`, but this is not suitable for me since I want to fetch everything with their key-value pair.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can't remove the forward slash try: `stripslashes()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

you can remove slashes before pushing it into array

```
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $row = stripslashes($row);
    array_push($info, $row);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to get everything fron your table into a array.

```
$stmt->execute();

$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
    $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        $c[$key] = $val;
    }
    $contents[] = $c;
}
```

With this code you can go though the $contents, and get the dir by using $content['dir']

```
foreach ($contents as $content) {

    echo $content['dir']

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer their question

Comment: Why isn't this a answer ? I answered the question with a way to fix it, and put it to a array. This way isn't failing the '/' and making a '\' in front. So this is deffinetly a answer ^^

Comment: That's *not* what they're asking for. Their issue was with unwanted slashes, no more.